# Pass a dictionary in try/except clause

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a use case that requires passing a dictionary in a try/exception clause in Python 3.x

The error message can be accessed as a string using `str()` function, but I can't figure out who to get it as a dictionary.

```py
try:
    raise RuntimeError({'a':2})
except Exception as e:
    error = e
    print(error['a'])
```

`e` is a RuntimeError object and I can't find any method that returns the message in its original format.

Comment: The argument to `RuntimeError` has to be a string. If you want different parameters to your error, you need to define a custom exception class.

Comment: @Barmar Where is it written the argument to `RuntimeError` has to be a string?

Comment: @wim https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError says "The associated value is a string indicating what precisely went wrong."

Comment: @Barmar That is quite different from saying "The argument to `RuntimeError` has to be a string".

Comment: Where does the associated value come from other than the argument?

Comment: At the beginning of that page it says "The associated value is usually passed as arguments to the exception class’s constructor." @wim

Comment: The docs are saying that the way the stdlib uses `RuntimeError` is usually with a string argument. It's not saying that it has to be a string.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Exceptions store their init args in an "args" attribute:

```
try: 
    raise RuntimeError({'a':2}) 
except Exception as e: 
    (the_dict,) = e.args 
    print(the_dict["a"])
```

That being said, if you want an exception type which has a structured key/value context associated, it would be best to define your own custom exception subclass for this purpose rather than re-use the standard library's [`RuntimeError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#RuntimeError) directly.  That's because if you catch such an exception and attempt to unpack the dictionary context, you would need to detect and handle your `RuntimeError` instances differently from `RuntimeError` instances that the standard library may have raised. Using a different type entirely will make it much cleaner and easier to distinguish these two cases in your code.